# Each loop returning duplicate data from Soundcloud API

Tags: jquery, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I'm trying to list multiple tracks on the same page using the Soundcloud API. I want to loop over each DIV so it pulls the correct individual data using the `/tracks` API reference. However it just pulls the same data into each div (same artwork, same audio etc). If I do a console log of the variable for the `/tracks` API ID reference then it correctly loops through each div and correctly lists the different ID's. Why is it pulling in the correct ID's but then pulling in duplicate data?

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Loop over each mix
  $(".mix").each(function(){

    // Set the mix ID as a variable
    var mixID = $(this).data("mix");

    // Test it's getting correct unique track ID's
    console.log($(this).data("mix"));

    // Get the track meta data
    SC.get('/tracks/'+mixID+'', function(track) {
      var artwork = track.artwork_url;
      var artwork = artwork.replace('-large', '-t500x500');

      $(".mix__user").html(track.user.username).attr("href", track.user.permalink_url);
      $(".mix__artwork").attr("src", artwork);
      $(".mix__waveform").attr("src", track.waveform_url);
    });

    // Stream the track
    SC.stream('/tracks/'+mixID+'', function(sound) {

    var is_playing = false;

    // Track controls
    $('.mix__control').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(is_playing === false){
            sound.start();
            is_playing = true;
            $(this).toggleClass("is_playing").html("Pause");

        } else if (is_playing === true) {
            sound.pause();
            is_playing = false;
            $(this).toggleClass("is_playing").html("Play");
        }
     });
   });
 });
});
```

There is some Craft CMS template language in the HTML.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mix') %}
    <article class="mix" data-mix="{{ entry.mixId }}">

    <div class="mix-meta">
            <button class="mix__control  ss-icon">Play</button>
            <img class="mix__artwork" src="">           
        <img class="mix__waveform" src="">
        </div>

      <a href="{{ entry.url}}" class="mix-wrap">
        <h1 class="mix__title">{{ entry.title }}</h1>
        <time class="mix__date" datetime="2008-02-14 20:00">{{ entry.postDate.format('d F Y') }}</time>

        <ol class="mix__tracklist">
        {% for block in entry.tracklisting %}
            {% if block.type == "tracklist" %}
                <li><span class="mix__artist">{{ block.artist }}</span> - <span class="mix__track">{{ block.track }}</span></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
      </a>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, my guess is that you're running into a problem with your jquery selectors updating every `$(".mix__XXXX")` on your page when you really only want to update the ones in the current `<article class="mix">`. You would want to change those selectors to `$(this).find(".mix__XXXX");`

Bonus tip: assigning $(this) to a variable to like `$this = $(this)` will keep jquery from having to run it's wrapping function every time.

**Update with closure:** (untested)

```
(function($theMix) {    
    SC.get('/tracks/'+mixID+'', function(track) {
      var artwork = track.artwork_url;
      var artwork = artwork.replace('-large', '-t500x500');

      $theMix.find(".mix__user").html(track.user.username).attr("href", track.user.permalink_url);
      $theMix.find(".mix__artwork").attr("src", artwork);
      $theMix.find(".mix__waveform").attr("src", track.waveform_url);
    });
})($(this));
```

Comment: I think you are right however 'this' in your example returns [object Window] as oppose to the parent 'mix'

Comment: I see. SC.get() is an ajax call which changes our context. That's fine. Let's wrap that bad boy in a closure. See the update to my answer.